# Array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, linux, gcc, struct

Here's the struct:

```
typedef struct state_machine{
char name;
struct state_machine *next0;
struct state_machine *next1;
}state;
```

and here's me trying to create an array of them

```
state[] states = {
      {'A', state+3, state+4},
      {'B', state,   state+5}, 
      {'C', state+4, state  }, 
      {'D', state+5, state+6}, 
      {'E', state+1, state+7}, 
      {'F', state+7, state+3}, 
      {'G', state+2, state+6}, 
      {'F', state+6, state+1}};
```

compiler catches the error on the first line, " state[] states = { "

expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘[’ token

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to:

```
state states[] = {
      {'A', states+3, states+4}, //You probably meant states, since state is a type
      {'B', states,   states+5}, 
      {'C', states+4, states  }, 
      {'D', states+5, states+6}, 
      {'E', states+1, states+7}, 
      {'F', states+7, states+3}, 
      {'G', states+2, states+6}, 
      {'F', states+6, states+1}};
```

In `C`, the `[]` should be after the variable name, not after the type.

Comment: error: expected expression before ‘state’
on every line when I do that

Comment: @user3365695: read the answer. You probabley forgot to change e.g `state+4` to `states+4`.

Comment: :falmpalm: can't believe I didn't see that

Comment: @user3365695, If you find the answer helpful, you should accept it.